# How to use directives in nomnoml?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I'm using [nomnoml](http://www.nomnoml.com/) to create an UML class diagram. In the nomnoml language reference there are instructions called "directives" but I can't figure out how to use them.

How do I put directives in my nomnoml code?

Comment: Open an issue on GitHub or send a support request e-mail to the author - both links are included in the project's about page and then you can write a [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) ;) Right now your unclear question does not fit into the "_..software tools commonly used by programmers.._" [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) category

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried to make my question clearer and opened an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Your issue https://github.com/skanaar/nomnoml/issues/8 was closed so welcome to Stack Overflow and now you can happily continue to the [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) part :)

Comment: Turned out I simply misunderstood how directives work. I thought they could be used on separate elements of a diagram. Thanks for your help =)

Comment: Thanks for the link for nomnoml. Another interesting tool falling into the category weird-text-to-uml-picture is https://www.websequencediagrams.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use directives you put them on their own line of code like this:

```
#zoom: 3
```

A directive influences the appearance of the whole diagram, it can't be used on a single element of it.